# AngularJS + UI Bootstrap Typeahead: preload value from object into input field

Tags: angularjs, typeahead, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to use AngularJS + UI Bootstrap Typeahead to fill in input field with name attribute of an object while I need to use id attribute of this object when the form is sent.

The problem is that when I try to preload the input with some previously saved value - the value of id attribute is displayed inside the input instead of the value of name attribute.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="form.product_id" typeahead="option.id as option.name for option in p.options | filter:$viewValue" />
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/honzzz/T3YFR/3/)

How do I preload the value of name attribute and still keep the desired functionality?

Comment: ur fiddle not working though

Comment: I see that it's not working in new builds of Chrome - it's not loading external scripts from github because strict MIME type checking is enabled. If you want to fiddle with it could you please use Firefox?

Comment: updated code have a look at my answer

Comment: Same fiddle but working: http://jsfiddle.net/hieuh25/CXnKD/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use the `product object` as `ng-model`. And then you can simply get the `id` use `form.product.id`.

<kbd>**[Demo on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CXnKD/2/)**</kbd>

```
<div ng-controller="MyTabCtrl"> <pre>Model: {{form.product.id | json}}</pre>
    <p>The goal is to show "Horay!" while the model is set to 1.</p>
        <input type="text" autocomplete="off" ng-model="form.product" typeahead="option as option.name for option in p.options | filter:$viewValue" />
    <p>Try to write "Audi".</p>
</div>
```